# Paypal how can I know which user donated?

Tags: paypal, donations

In my site I added a Donate button, generated from paypal. When it is clicked, the user is redirected to paypal. Then, he might or might not donate to me. However, if he does, I want to add him and the amount he donated to my database. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to trigger a POST to your database with the information.